# Error converting data type numeric to int

Tags: sql-server, database, int, type-conversion, numeric

I have two databases on the same SQL Server. Same code.

I have a stored procedure with an input parameter `@Test INT`. In one database when I pass a `NUMERIC` value into that input, it gets truncated and everything works fine. In the other one, when doing the same thing, I get the following error:

> *Error converting data type numeric to int*

Here is the stored procedure signature:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[blProductGetTariff]
(
    @CurrencyID             INT,
    @ProductID              INT,
    @TradeDate              DATETIME,
    @TotalDays              INT,
    @onTariff               NUMERIC(22, 10) OUTPUT
)
```

And here's how I invoke that stored procedure:

```
EXEC blProductGetTariff @CurrencyID, 
                        @MTPLY_VolumeID, 
                        @TradeDate, 
                        @VolumeParam, 
                        @VolumeMultiplierRate OUTPUT
```

`@VolumeParam` is numeric and it gets fed fine into `@TotalDays` in one db, but not in the second one.

What would be the possible database setting responsible for this, and is there one? Or I'm missing something, and there are other reasons for this weird behaviour?

**UPDATE**: Darin made a very good point in one of his comments below: "Also, looking at your code above, you might be overflowing the int if you are passing a numeric(22,10). In which case you have to make the numeric smaller or pass a bigint".. He was right. So changing INT to BIGINT resolved the problem, although I still do not understand why it does not happen in the first database, where everything works fine with INT and I use exactly the same data(actually the same file) for testing.

Comment: Please give some code that works fine in one DB but not in the other.

Comment: Please check that arithabort and arithignore are also the same on both databases (per Darin below).  And for that matter that the compatability level is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are dealing with a database wide setting for NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT, arithabort or arithignore.  You can read more here:

arithignore
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184341.aspx

arithabort
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190306.aspx

NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188791.aspx

I think doing this before your query will ignore your error.  This might not be what you want to do in the long run though.  Fixing the proc is probably best.

```
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
```

The databases most likely have different values for NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT.  Right click the database in SSMS and click properties.  Go to options and you will find this setting under Miscellaneous.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Darin..

I don't think this is it though, because both databases have the same NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT setting.

Comment: Try putting SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF above your query and see if  that fails.

Comment: Have you tried running something like this in SSMS?  You'll have to replace the #'s with @'s.

declare #numeric numeric(9,2),
  #int int
set #numeric = 50.23
set #int = #numeric
select #int

If that works you could just declare another variable and do the conversion before you pass it to the stored proc.

Comment: Also, looking at your code above, you might be overflowing the int if you are passing a numeric(22,10).  In which case you have to make the numeric smaller or pass a bigint.

Comment: Thank you very much, Darin. I changed INT to BIGINT and everything started working in the database where I had problems before. It's weird because I used exactly the same data to test it in two databases and debuging proved it again. Is there a reason for that? 

Thank you very much for your help, really appreciate it.